# How can Parent Form Access Children Inputs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a customizable login component so that by default, the user doesn't have to include inputs, however if they need to customize them they can just pass in the inputs and include a ref.

For example:

```
// normal usage
<Register type={'username-password'} />

// custom usage
<Register type='username-password'>
  <input ref='email' />
  <input ref='password' />
  <input ref='submit' />
</Register>
```

However i'm having trouble getting access to the input elements when the Register component's form triggers `onSubmit`. I tried cycling through `this.props.children` but couldn't figure out how to get inside. How can I access the text values?

I realize that you really shouldn't do this but in this case i'm not sure how to work around it and still have a nice API.

Comment: not sure why you have the <Register>?

Comment: @JordanDavis Oh sorry for the lack of context. Register is the component i'm making to login to the system (a Meteor app actually).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, though my intuition tells me there should be a more elegant way. Hope this helps.

```
var Register = React.createClass({
    // omitted the other lifecycle and defaults. no need for example.

    componentWillMount: function() {
        var chillin = this.props.children.map(function(elem){
            return elem.props.value;
        })

        this.setState({
            chillin: chillin
        })
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
                <div>
                    Input Values:  {this.state.chillin}
                </div>
        )
    }
});


React.render(
        <Register name="test" >
            <input type="text" value="blue" ref="email" />
            <input type="text" value="99999" ref="age" />
        </Register>, document.getElementById('r'));
```

note: of course, I hardcoded the value in there as a quick proof of concept.

Comment: Doh, that was so simple :) Thanks! Do you know offhand if looping through the children would work on the form's onSubmit callback (after render)? At any rate i'll try this tonight!